# Utilizar clases en PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

Después de revisar la documentación de GitHub gracias a un usuario de esta comunidad confirmo que hay dos maneras de incluir estas librerías en el código PHP mediante composer o mediante la asignación de la ruta a los ficheros que las contienen de esta manera: (que es la que he elegido)

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

En mi caso he sustituido path/to/ por assets/ que es donde tengo los recursos.

En todo caso al ejecutar el código el logfile me devuelve este error:

*[Tue Oct 17 10:17:10.331051 2017] [:error] [pid 3879] [client 192.168.0.184:50679] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in /var/www/test/sendMail.php on line 7*

Comment: ¿Cómo has instalado la librería? Si lo haces mediante `composer`, entonces solo tienes que hacer uso del `namespace` de la clase en cuestión, en tu caso `PHPMailer\PHPMailer`, y el autoload de composer hará el resto. ¿Lo conoces?

Comment: @Muriano gracias por tu respuesta. No conozco composer ni el procedimiento para instalar la librería. Si me puedes dar algún dato mas estaría agradecido.

Comment: Puedes obtener más información sobre cómo instalar PHPMailer correctamente en esta web: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading

Comment: Cuando usas los 'require' asegurate que la ruta que estas indicando es la correcta

Comment: @LombardaArda los require van a las rutas adecuadas seguro.

Comment: @Muriano gracias por el enlace a la documentación, ya lo había revisado pero me ha hecho clarificar el post que he actualizado con la forma escogida para incluir las librerías y acceder a ellas. Aún y así me devuelve un error el logfile relacionado con USE.